# Sub Query vs Table Filter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have have been assigned to resolve Performance issue of a Stored Procedure.

```
Select TableTwo.Column1, DatabaseTwo..TableThree.Column2, Sum(TableTwo.Column3) As Column3  
     --- Section 1
    from TableOne  
    inner join TableTwo on TableOne.Column4 = TableTwo.Column4 
    inner join DatabaseTwo..TableThree on TableTwo.Column1 = DatabaseTwo..TableThree.Column5  
    inner join TableFour on TableOne.Column6 = TableFour.Column6  
    inner join TableFive on TableFour.Column7 = TableFive.Column7  
    inner join TableSix on TableFour.Column8 = TableSix.Column8  
    inner join TableSeven on TableSeven.Column7 = TableFive.Column7  
    inner join TableEight on TableOne.Column9 = TableEight.Column9  
    inner join TableNine on TableFour.Column10 = TableNine.Column10  
    inner join TableTen on TableFive.Column11 = TableTen.Column11   
    inner join TableEleven on TableFive.Column12 = TableEleven.Column12   
    inner join TableTwelve on TableTwelve.Column7 = TableFive.Column7 and TableTwelve.Column9 = TableOne.Column9   
    inner join TableThirteen on TableThirteen.Column13 = TableFour.Column13   
    inner join TableSeventeen on TableSeventeen.Column14 = TableOne.Column14   
    where TableFive.Column15 = 3


    --- Section 2
    and TableOne.Column6 in  (Select TableOne.Column6 
                                from TableOne, TableTwo, TableFour  
                                Where TableOne.Column4 = TableTwo.Column4 
                                and TableOne.Column6 = TableFour.Column6 
                                and TableFour.Column16 >= @StartDate 
                                and TableFour.Column16< @EndDate )  


    --- Section 3                       
    and TableFour.Column6 In (Select TableFour.Column6 
                                from TableFour,TableEightteen,TableNineTeen 
                                Where TableFour.Column7 = TableNineTeen.Column7 
                                and TableEightteen.Column17 = TableNineTeen.Column17 
                                and TableFour.Column10 = TableNineTeen.Column10 
                                and TableEightteen.Column18 > TableFour.Column16
                                )  


    --- Section 4
    and TableFour.Column7 Not In (SELECT Column7 
                                FROM TableFour 
                                GROUP BY Column7, Column10 
                                HAVING ( COUNT(Column7) > 1 ) 
                                and Column7 = TableFour.Column7 
                                and Column10 = TableFour.Column10
                                )  


    --- Section 5                           
    and TableOne.Column6 in (Select TableOne.Column6 
                                 from TableOne, TableTwo, TableFour , TableFive 
                                 Where TableOne.Column4 = TableTwo.Column4 
                                 and TableOne.Column6 = TableFour.Column6 
                                 and TableFive.Column7 = TableFour.Column7 
                                 and TableFive.Column12=@Column12
                                 )                  

    Group By TableTwo.Column1, DatabaseTwo..TableThree.[Column2]  
    Order By  TableTwo.Column1, DatabaseTwo..TableThree.[Column2]
```

My Question is as per my understanding

1. Since Section2 has all tables that Section1 has with same join conditions therefore filtering condition `and TableFour.Column16 >= @StartDate and TableFour.Column16< @EndDate` of section2 should be transferred to Section1 and this will result in same query. AM I right?
2. Same scenario is with section6 which has all tables that Section1 but with one extra filter statement `and TableFive.Column12=@Column12`

and by removing section2 and section6 we can avoid extra conditions

Comment: Posting an execution plan will help us help you !

Comment: @Kin how SQL work internally ? Is  'IN condition with same joins and one extra condition' not equal to apply filter on main outer query instead of using IN with same joins ? or is this depends on Plan?

Comment: please read - [How do I provide an execution plan to someone for analysis?](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/797/8783)

Comment: @Kin, thanks a new thing for me is we can replace table names in execution plan files, ok will be here again with execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just look at TableOne, TableTwo, and TableFour
Most of the condition in the "in where" in are already covered in the join
And suggest you use join on for all

```
Select TableTwo.Column1, DatabaseTwo..
from TableOne  
inner join TableTwo  on TableOne.Column4 = TableTwo.Column4 
inner join TableFour on TableOne.Column6 = TableFour.Column6         
where 1 = 1
--- Section 2
and TableOne.Column6 in  (Select TableOne.Column6 
                            from TableOne, TableTwo, TableFour  
                            Where TableOne.Column4 = TableTwo.Column4  -- covered in base join 
                            and TableOne.Column6 = TableFour.Column6   -- covered in base join
                            and TableFour.Column16 >= @StartDate 
                            and TableFour.Column16 <  @EndDate )
```

Pretty sure this is the same query
Not sure if it is faster but I doubt is is slower
The query optimizer has a better chance of filtering early

```
Select TableTwo.Column1, DatabaseTwo..
from TableOne  
inner join TableTwo  on  TableOne.Column4 = TableTwo.Column4 
inner join TableFour on  TableOne.Column6 = TableFour.Column6   
                     and TableFour.Column16 >= @StartDate 
                     and TableFour.Column16 <  @EndDate
```

as for

```
and TableFour.Column6 In (Select TableFour.Column6 
                                from TableFour,TableEightteen,TableNineTeen 
                                Where TableFour.Column7 = TableNineTeen.Column7 
                                and TableEightteen.Column17 = TableNineTeen.Column17 
                                and TableFour.Column10 = TableNineTeen.Column10 
                                and TableEightteen.Column18 > TableFour.Column16
                                )
```

pretty sure that can be

```
join TableEightteen on  TableEightteen.Column18 > TableFour.Column16 
join TableNineTeen  on  TableFour.Column7  = TableNineTeen.Column7  
                    and TableFour.Column10 = TableNineTeen.Column10  
                    and TableEightteen.Column17 = TableNineTeen.Column17
```

Comment: Actually yes this is what i am trying to conclude both statements will return same result set or is there any scenario which is hidden from me and will return different result?

Comment: "Pretty sure this is the same query"